# Daemon to monitor activity

Tags: iphone, scheduled-tasks

I am working on some kind of communication which might get interrupted once in a while. For this I need some kind of monitor that fires after 5 seconds, if not in the meantime has been reset by any valid communication to start waiting for another 5 seconds, and so on....

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) class.